# Django: Settings' object has no attribute 'LOGFILE'

Tags: django, attributeerror

Here's my code

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.conf import settings


class Utils(object):

    def get_logs(self):
        try:
            with open(settings.LOGFILE, 'r') as fd:
                data_logs = fd.readlines()
            return data_logs
        except IOError:
            return []

    def write_log(self, content):
        date = datetime.now()
        with open(settings.LOGFILE, 'a+') as fd:
            fd.write("%s  :  %s\n" % (date.strftime("%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S"), content))
```

When I run my server, Django gives produces the error `Django: Settings' object has no attribute 'LOGFILE'`. What is causing this?

Comment: So... have you defined `LOGFILE` in your settings?

Comment: no. how can i do that?

Comment: Modify your project's `settings.py` to add this setting. You might want to start with the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/) which takes you through the basics of how to set up and configure things like settings.

Comment: Oh yeah! I just find it

Comment: this line LOGFILE = '%s/ex03/history.logs' % BASE_DIR